# How to add the highcharts of Gatling result in my angular application?

Tags: angular, highcharts, gatling

I would use Highcharts of Gatling report  in my angular application, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You're not allowed to do that. The license we purchased from Highsoft in order to be able to redistribute their library in our bundle doesn't allow you to do that.